# Python extract longest patterns when nesting single and double quote

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have some text that involves nesting single and double quotes, eg:

```
 """ The "'quick', 'brown fox'", 'jumps over the "lazy dog"' """
```

I want to extract the "outer-most" level of quoted strings, that is, in this case I'd like to have two sub-strings, `'quick', 'brown fox'` and `jumps over the "lazy dog"`, but not the first `The`. This is essentially matching pairs of quotes and find the longest one. How can I do it most efficiently (assuming my input text is large)?

Comment: `"[^"]+"|'[^']+'`?

Comment: Off-topic, obviously.

Comment: @ctwheels it seems to work fast for this quick fox toy and one of my real-example in practice -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can *easily* be accomplished using regex

```
"[^"]+"|'[^']+'
```

- Match either of the following options

  - `"[^"]+"`

    - `"` Match this literally
    - `[^"]+` Match any character except `"` one or more times
    - `"` Match this literally
  - `'[^']+'`

    - `'` Match this literally
    - `[^']+` Match any character except `'` one or more times
    - `'` Match this literally

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##FYxBDsIgEEX3nGLCZiA13bj2JE2b1JZaFBgcqFrj3ZH@3Uve@3HPK4VzKdZH4gxshEhwAZZ1@Nzs9MAT4JXpHWChD8pK983HBPQyDHk1IN343WGmm8QaCT5y007ko3VGHUfdIPtG/rAbsG8OSYvINmTF7WLDPDqnktal/AE)

```
import re

s = r""""'quick', 'brown fox'", 'jumps over the "lazy dog"'"""
r = re.compile(""""[^"]+"|'[^']+'""")
print(r.findall(s))
```

Result:

```
['"\'quick\', \'brown fox\'"', '\'jumps over the "lazy dog"\'']
```

Answer (score 1):

`shlex.split` does exactly what you're looking for:

```
import shlex

s = """"'quick', 'brown fox'", 'jumps over the "lazy dog"'"""

toks = shlex.split(s)
print(toks)
```

result:

```
["'quick', 'brown fox',", 'jumps over the "lazy dog"']
```

(I must say I'm pleasantly surprised to see that it can cope with single or double quotes, I only used it to split according to double quotes, but that one tries hard to emulate Unix-like command line tokenizing)

EDIT: the question has been modified in the meantime. To get rid of the first unquoted chars, I've added a regex to remove all chars until the first quote:

```
import shlex,re

s = """ The "'quick', 'brown fox'", 'jumps over the "lazy dog"' """

toks = shlex.split(re.sub('^[^\'"]*',"",s))
```

output:

```
["'quick', 'brown fox',", 'jumps over the "lazy dog"']
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution! However although it works for my posted toy example, it does not necessary "extract" the pattern for me. for example `""" a, b, 'c', "d, 'e'" """` results in `['a,', 'b,', 'c,', "d, 'e'"]` when only `c` and `d, 'e'` is desired ...

Comment: Sorry, I've revised my question above.